# Is there a way to programmatically turn OFF WiFi in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wifi, transmission

But in such a way that there is absolutely NO TRANSMISSION out of it? No searching for hotspots nor any keepalives or any other transmission?

Thank you very much,
Yaron.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6170507/1447466

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [How to use the connection settings task for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh394011(v=vs.105).aspx). You can use the

```
var navigate = Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-location:"));
```

which will navigate you to the settings page where you can turn off and on the wifi settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change them programmatically, but you can ask a user to change them and redirect a user to the `Settings` page (for this purpose use `ConnectionSettingsTask` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394011(v=vs.105).aspx).

This is because the platform leaves these kinds of settings in the user's control at all times.

```
ConnectionSettingsTask connectionSettingsTask = new ConnectionSettingsTask();
connectionSettingsTask.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.WiFi;
connectionSettingsTask.Show();
```

The closest you can get is to programmatically launch the WiFi settings page where the user can modify the setting:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-wifi:"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 you can use [this API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.radios.aspx)

There is a sample of its usage published by Microsoft [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/radiomanager/cs)