# Disconnecting without disconnecting?

Tags: c#

For some of my projects, I have to disable my connection for like 5 seconds and then enable it again.

How do I do this now (this is not the best solution, but I'm using the Windows VPN):

- I've setted up a VPN which does not let any internet trough, which makes me sort-of disconnect, but is faster then Wi-Fi reconnecting.

So I basicly want to know a method to disconnect, like connecting to a broken VPN (no Wi-Fi).

In C# code.

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Take [a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172875/how-to-disable-enable-network-connection-in-c-sharp):

Using netsh Command, you can enable and disable “Local Area Connection”

```
  interfaceName is “Local Area Connection”.

  static void Enable(string interfaceName)
    {
     System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi =
            new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("netsh", "interface set interface \"" + interfaceName + "\" enable");
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo = psi;
        p.Start();
    }

    static void Disable(string interfaceName)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi =
            new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("netsh", "interface set interface \"" + interfaceName + "\" disable");
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo = psi;
        p.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Mmm,will tru this defenetly :)

Comment: You mean "Will try"? Do it definitely :)

Comment: Yeah and i tried it like:
Enable("Local Area Connection");

Comment: Could be im wrong but is that solution for Ethernet only? http://i.imgur.com/dzGJ0rG.png i dont tink i have a Local Area Connection atm

Comment: Ill try this with cable, cant do that atm soon, if it works with cable its fine too :)