# how to get network connection list in my computer with .NET?

Tags: c#, networking

how to get network connection list in my computer with c#
vpn list or other

in windows 7 this path Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections

i need for write a function to connect to internet in c#

Comment: Are you looking for network interfaces, VPNs, TCP sessions, connected shares, or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're looking for the list of network interfaces.

The [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.aspx) class is probably what you are after, specifically the [GetAllNetworkInterfaces()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces(v=VS.90).aspx) method.

To get the same list as Control Panel, I suspect you will also need to filter on the **NetworkInterfaceType** property value, to skip loopback and tunneling interfaces.

Comment: i need  to get active and deactivate connection list but in you answer only active connection showed

Comment: I don't believe you can do this using the .NET APIs, you will probably need to use P/Invoke.

If you need this for programmatically enabling/disabling a particular interface, there is this existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860673/programatically-disable-enable-network-interface

Comment: no this link for disable card  but i looking for connect to internet