# Disable-Enable Ethernet Interface Connection using C++ or Qt in Window 7 64bit

Tags: c++, windows, qt, interface, ethernet

I'm trying to come up with an easy solution to my "buggy" Ethernet camera. The thing is after establishing a TCP connection to reach faster FPS the camera ignores if someone is reading the socket buffer and blocks if the program unexpectedly stops without "sending end of connection" message. I come up with an stupid/easy solution. Disable and re-enable the Ethernet connection works. It works if the camera is directly connected to the computer. But now I have to program it.

I've found someone with similar problems but I want something more Qt like.

[Programmatically disable/enable network interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860673/programatically-disable-enable-network-interface)

Does QT 5.4.0 have some API or Library to do it? Does C++ have something similar?

As the firs link says Microsoft suggested **Win32_NetworkAdapter class** but I have never used it. Will it work in QT with msvc 2010 used in a W7 64bit SO?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216%28VS.85%29.aspx

Thanks!

Comment: If you are compiling with MSVC, almost all of the Win32 libraries are available and fairly straight forward to use.  Occasionally, the function calls are not included in `windows.h` and you have to load the library explicitly to be able to access the functions.  I've done this on many occasions, often after finding examples on http://www.codeproject.com/ or the msdn docs or autohotkey.com that do exactly what I need in windows then I ported it to work in C++ in MSVC, or MingW.

Comment: Ok I will try codeproject.com! Tnx