# Disconnect Network C#

Tags: c#, wpf, networking, disconnect

Is it possible for me to disconnect the systems connection to the internet without the need for detecting the network adapter etc.?

I would like to add this functionality to my software but can't find a proper method.

Can anyone shine some light on this.

I am running it through a WPF app.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this. No idea if it's what your lookng for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83756/how-to-programmatically-enable-disable-network-interfaces-windows-xp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to implement your requirement, the best is depend on the platforms which you want support and for other requirements.

- You can disable all Network cards.
- You can temporary change the routing table.
- You can use WFP ([Windows Filtering Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/network/wfp.mspx--) see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366510.aspx) to block connection of the level of firewall, but without direct usage of the firewall.

I am sure that it is not the full list of possible ways. I know no simple .NET API which can you use.

You should be careful to be sure that after the end of your application the computer can work as before.