# Script to change ip address on windows

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, batch-file, ipv4

I use my computer to communicate with a piece of hardware via ethernet. To communicate with this device I set my ip to 192 168 0 11, subnet mask to 255 255 255 0, and default gateway to 192 168 0 1 for IPv4. To use the internet, I choose "Obtain an IP address automatically" via control panel.

I'd like to have a script that allows my to quickly choose one or the other ethernet setting - hardware or internet.

I program mostly in python but maybe there is a batch file solution.

Thanks,

Barry.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83756/how-to-programmatically-enable-disable-network-interfaces-windows-xp

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the Python [WMI module](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html) to do this (install the [PyWin32 extensions](http://starship.python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html) and the WMI module before running these scripts). Here is how to configure things to talk to the hardware device:

```
import wmi

# Obtain network adaptors configurations
nic_configs = wmi.WMI().Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration(IPEnabled=True)

# First network adaptor
nic = nic_configs[0]

# IP address, subnetmask and gateway values should be unicode objects
ip = u'192.168.0.11'
subnetmask = u'255.255.255.0'
gateway = u'192.168.0.1'

# Set IP address, subnetmask and default gateway
# Note: EnableStatic() and SetGateways() methods require *lists* of values to be passed
nic.EnableStatic(IPAddress=[ip],SubnetMask=[subnetmask])
nic.SetGateways(DefaultIPGateway=[gateway])
```

Here is how to revert to obtaining an IP address automatically (via DHCP):

```
import wmi

# Obtain network adaptors configurations
nic_configs = wmi.WMI().Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration(IPEnabled=True)

# First network adaptor
nic = nic_configs[0]

# Enable DHCP
nic.EnableDHCP()
```

Note: in a production script you should check the values returned by [EnableStatic()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390383%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), [SetGateways()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393301%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [EnableDHCP()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390378%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). ('0' means success, '1' means reboot required and other values are described on the MSDN pages linked to by the method names. Note: for EnableStatic() and SetGateways(), the error codes are returned as lists).

Full information on all the functionality of the Win32NetworkAdapterConfiguration class can also be [found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Note: I tested this with Python 2.7, but as PyWIn32 and WMI modules are available for Python 3, I believe you should be able to get this working for Python 3 by removing the "u" from before the string literals.

Comment: Nice answer, except that it's not clear how to tell between several network interfaces if there're more than one (`nic.Description` for that) and that the script must be called with Administrator rights (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811372/how-to-code-a-bat-file-to-always-run-as-admin-mode)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the *subprocess* module to start

```
netsh interface ip set address [params]
```

Start this from the commandline (without[params]) to get some help how to use it. Then you can do

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("netsh interface ip set address ....".split())
```

**Update:**

For those who's too busy to rtfm,

```
netsh interface ip set address lan static 192.168.0.100 255.255.255.0
netsh interface ip set address lan dhcp
```

here `lan` is the name of the network interface to configure, 192.168.0.100 is ip address, 255.255.255.0 is network mask. The first command sets static address, the second reverts to dhcp.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some details, hope you don't mind ;)

Answer (score -1):

Actually very simple to do (windows only) (uses preinstalled libraries only):

```
import os; os.system("ipconfig /renew")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
import subprocess

from subprocess import PIPE
def find_net_device():
    cmd ='netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces'.split()

    result = subprocess.run(cmd, universal_newlines = True,
                            stdout = subprocess.PIPE)                              
    result = result.stdout
    result = result.split('connected')[2]
    result = result.split('\n')[0]
    result = result.strip()
    return result








def change_ip(ip):
    adapter = find_net_device()
    change =f'netsh interface ip set address {adapter} static {ip} 255.255.255.0'
    change = change.split()


change_ip('165.22.64.68')
```

#again back to normal

```
def back2normal():
    adapter = find_net_device()
    normal = f'netsh interface ip set address {adapter} dhcp'
    subprocess.run(normal,stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use vbscript to change IP Address,

```
Dim strIPAddress, strSubnetMask,strGateway, intGatewayMetric, strDns1, strDns2, objWMIService, colItems, stradaptername, objFSO
Const ForReading = 1 
Const ForAppending = 8
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set OutPutFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\ProgramData\test.txt" ,2 , True)
Set InterfaceName = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapter Where NetConnectionStatus >= 0")
If objFSO.FileExists("C:\ProgramData\test.txt") Then
Set OutPutFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\ProgramData\test1.txt" ,2 , True)
End If
For Each objItem in InterfaceName
If objFSO.FileExists("C:\ProgramData\test.txt") Then
arrInterfaces = objItem.NetConnectionID
'wscript.echo "test: " &arrInterfaces
Set objFileToWrite = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\ProgramData\test.txt",8,true)
ObjFileToWrite.WriteLine(arrInterfaces)
objFileToWrite.Close
Set objFileToWrite = Nothing
End If
next
If objFSO.FileExists("C:\ProgramData\test.txt") Then
Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\ProgramData\test.txt",1)
strFileText = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
objFileToRead.Close
Set objFileToRead = Nothing
'wscript.echo "obtained" &strFileText
End If
Result = inputbox("Enter the AdapterName: " &vbCrLf &strFileText)
If Result = "" then
'wscript.echo "user selected cancel"
Else
strIPAddress=InputBox("Enter Static IP Adrress: ")
strSubnetMask =InputBox("Enter SubnetMask: " )
strGateway=InputBox("Enter Default Gateway: ")
strDns1=InputBox("Enter Preferred DNS: ")
strDns2=InputBox("Enter Alternate DNS: ")
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Windows\System32"
objShell.Run "netsh interface ip set address name=""" & Result & """ static " & strIPAddress & " " & strSubnetMask & " " & strGateway & " " & intGatewayMetric, 0, True
objShell.Run "netsh interface ip set dns name=" & Result & " static "& strDns1, 0, True
objShell.Run "netsh interface ip add dns name=" & Result & " addr="& strDns2, 0, True
Set objShell = Nothing: Set obj=Nothing
End If
WScript.Quit
```