# EnableDHCP() returns 81 :Unable to configure DHCP service

Tags: python, vb.net, python-3.x, wmi, pywin32

i tried to change my ip automatically (via DHCP)
described in this post:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580834/script-to-change-ip-address-on-windows)

with this bit of code:

```
import wmi

# Obtain network adaptors configurations
nic_configs = wmi.WMI().Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration(IPEnabled=True)

# First network adaptor
nic = nic_configs[0]

# Enable DHCP
nic.EnableDHCP()
```

but i get returned the response value 81 as tuple : (81,)
which means : "Unable to configure DHCP service."
according to msdn homepage : [enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390378%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

I'm running the script with python 3.3.2.

need some help/advise. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using windows 7. Make sure to run the script as administrator.