# What is the cause of the error in this Python WMI script? (Windows 8.1) (Network adapter configuration) (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, windows, wmi

I am trying to make a Python script that will set my IP address to a static one instead of a dynamic one. I have searched up methods for this and the WMI implementation for Python seemed to be the best option. The stackoverflow question I got the information about is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7581831/5899439).

I can get the IP address to be set to the static address but then I have to set the DNS server as well. [This site here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/405339-replace-static-dns-settings-with-wmi-and-powershell) is where I got the basis for the DNS setting but it is causing problems.

**Traceback from IDLE**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\james_000\Desktop\SetIP.py", line 18, in <module>
    c = nic.SetDNSServerSearchOrder(dns)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 431, in __call__
    handle_com_error ()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wmi.py", line 241, in handle_com_error
    raise klass (com_error=err)
x_wmi: <x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0,
u'SWbemProperty', u'Type mismatch ', None, 0, -2147217403), None)>
```

**SetIP.py**

```
import wmi

nic_configs = wmi.WMI('').Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration(IPEnabled=True)

# First network adaptor
nic = nic_configs[0]

# IP address, subnetmask and gateway values should be unicode objects
ip = u'192.168.0.151'
subnetmask = u'255.255.255.0'
gateway = u'192.168.0.1'
dns = u'192.168.0.1'

# Set IP address, subnetmask and default gateway
# Note: EnableStatic() and SetGateways() methods require *lists* of values to be passed
a = nic.EnableStatic(IPAddress=[ip],SubnetMask=[subnetmask])
b = nic.SetGateways(DefaultIPGateway=[gateway])
c = nic.SetDNSServerSearchOrder(dns)
d = nic.SetDynamicDNSRegistration(true)

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
```

Please don't add solutions in comments as it makes it harder for other people to learn about how to fix the problem.

Comment: Can you include the relevant snippet of your code in the question itself, rather than instructing the user to download the file?

Comment: @brianpck ah yeah... I'll do that now

Comment: You need to read [mcve]. The code needs to be in the question itself, not in an external link.

Comment: @brianpck thanks. I will remember about that next time. Bookmarking now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetDNSServerSearchOrder is looking for an array of Strings

```
c = nic.SetDNSServerSearchOrder(dns)
```

should be

```
c = nic.SetDNSServerSearchOrder([dns])
```

Comment: derp... thank you. Sometimes, I wish error messages were able to understand the library and therefore be able to tell you went wrong...