# How to connect to device via Ethernet using static IP Address in Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, ipv4, static-ip-address, network-interface

I need to connect to a device via an Ethernet connection on Windows and have to set a static IP Address and Submask for this.

I need to create a Python script, which automates this workflow. The workflow is the following on Windows (see https://pynq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/appendix/assign_a_static_ip.html):

1. Go to Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> Network Connections
2. Find your Ethernet network interface, usually Local Area Connection
3. Double click on the network interface to open it, and click on Properties
4. Select Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) and click Properties
5. Select Use the following IP address
6. Set the Ip address to 192.168.2.1 (or any other address in the same range as the board)
7. Set the subnet mask to 255.255.255.0 and click OK

Of course, one needs admin rights to execute this. I am using the `pyuac` package for this (https://pypi.org/project/pyuac/).

This is my code so far (some is similar to [Script to change ip address on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580834/script-to-change-ip-address-on-windows)). When I execute the `change_nic_ip()` method only, it apparently changes my WiFi ip address, because I don't have an internet connection after running the script.

```
import pyuac

def change_nic_ip():
    # Obtain network adapters configurations
    nic_configs = wmi.WMI().Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration(IPEnabled=True)

    # First network adapter
    nic = nic_configs[0]

    print(nic.IPAddress[0]) # debug message

    # IP address, subnetmask and gateway values should be unicode objects
    ip = '192.168.2.1'
    subnetmask = '255.255.255.0'

    # Set IP address and subnetmask
    static_ip = nic.EnableStatic(IPAddress=[ip], SubnetMask=[subnetmask])

    if 0 in static_ip:
        print("Successful changing to static IP address!")
    else:
        raise ValueError("Error: Changing to static IP address unsuccessful! Error Code: " + static_ip)

    print(nic.IPAddress[0]) # debug message

    # TODO check if static IP Address is actually correct


def revert_to_automatic_ip():
    # Obtain network adapters configurations
    nic_configs = wmi.WMI().Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration(IPEnabled=True)

    # First network adapter
    nic = nic_configs[0]

    # Enable DHCP
    dhcp = nic.EnableDHCP()

    if 0 in dhcp:
        print("Successfully changed to automatic IP configuration!")
    else:
        raise ValueError("Error: Changing to automatic IP address unsuccessful! Error Code: " + dhcp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not pyuac.isUserAdmin():
        pyuac.runAsAdmin()
    else:
        change_nic_ip()
        revert_to_automatic_ip()

        # TODO remove
        import time
        time.sleep(3)
```

TLDR: Tried using the following python script to change Ethernet IP Address from automatic to a static IP address, but it seems to change Wifi IP Address.

EDIT: I think I was off by one.
`nic = nic_configs[0]` needs to be `nic = nic_configs[1]`