# How to interrupt connection to db for test purpose?

Tags: database, windows, linux, connection

I have an application that connects to database on remote server.
I need to test how application will works in case when temporary lost connection.
I cannot disconnect network cable. Does it possible to interrupt temporarily connection and after restore? OS - windows.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you disable your network? You can do that from Network Adapter settings.

Comment: I cannot disable my network throw control panel. I think that some application can do.

Comment: By you cannot, do you mean that you do not have the privilege of that?

Comment: Why you ask about privileges? How it can be related to my question? I create connection in my application. For test I need to check how it works when connection will be interrupted. It must reconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a software firewall if you have one that blocks certain applications. Even the Windows firewall (Win 7 & Vista) has this option.

Comment: I cannot change firewall settings.  Now I think to install some db emulator to check connection...

Answer (score 1):

In windows you can use `netsh` command to disable a network interface. See the usage in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/86611/112744). But I believe this command behaves differently according to the OS version...

If it does not work maybe try the [devcon](http://wlanbook.com/enable-disable-wireless-card-command-line/) utility.

> The DevCon utility is a command-line utility that acts as an
>   alternative to Device Manager. Using DevCon, you can enable, disable,
>   restart, update, remove, and query individual devices or groups of
>   devices. DevCon also provides information that is relevant to the
>   driver developer and is not available in Device Manager.
>
> You can use DevCon with Microsoft Windows 2000, Windows XP, and Windows Server
>   2003. You cannot use DevCon with Windows 95, Windows 98, or Windows Millennium Edition.

Comment: Can you further explain your requirements/constraints then?

Answer (score 0):

For me clumsy is the best fit solution I found to simulate bad network conditions.
https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/

saw it here: https://serverfault.com/q/302299